# Replicating a SQL Server database for read access

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I have an application that is in production with its own database for more than 10 years.

I'm currently developing a new application (kind of a reporting application) that only needs read access to the database.

In order not to be too much linked to the database and to be able to use newer DAL (Entity Framework 6 Code First) I decided to start from a new empty database, and I only added the tables and columns I need (different names than the production one).

Now I need some way to update the new database with the production database regularly (would be best if it is -almost- immediate).

I hesitated to ask this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com but I'm not necessarily limited to only using SQL Server for the job (I can develop and run some custom application if needed).

I already made some searches and had those (part-of) solutions :

1. Using **Transactional Replication** to create a smaller database (with only the tables/columns I need). But as far as I can see, the fact that I have different table names / columns names will be problematic. So I can use it to create a smaller database that is automatically replicated by SQL Server, but I would still need to replicate this database to my new one (it may avoid my production database to be too much stressed?)
2. Using **triggers** to insert/update/delete the rows
3. Creating some **custom job** (either a SQL Job or some Windows Service that runs every X minutes) that updates the necessary tables (I have a LastEditDate that is updated by a trigger on my tables, so I can know that a row has been updated since my last replication)

Do you some advice or maybe some other solutions that I didn't foresee?

Thanks

Comment: I would drop your new tables.  Replicate the old tables using transactional replication, and then if you must have the "new" table/column names for your app, just build views on the replicated tables with those names.

Comment: Extract, Transform, Load or ETL is another approach which is especially appropriate when the structures are not identical.  this can be scripted manually or done with SSIS(although I dislike SSIS, it might be good for such a simple case).  However, I would go with Jiggs suggestion or simply use Entity Framework database first approach against the old database, instead of code first, and use a repository or other DB layer to encapsulate queries that deal with the nastiness of the old database.

Comment: For Read only access the easiest way to go would be Log-shipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we went for the Trigger solution. We don't have that much changes a day (maybe 500, 1000 top), and it didn't put too much pressure on the current database. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Transactional replication is the better than using triggers.
Too much resources would be used in source server/database due to the trigger fires by each DML transaction.

Transactional rep could be scheduled as a SQL job and run it few times a day/night or as a part of nightly scheduled job. IT really depends on how busy the source db is...

There is one more thing that you could try - DB mirroring. it depends on your sql server version.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd use transactional replication, but keep the table/column names the same. If you have some real reason why you need them to change (I honestly can't think of any good ones and a lot of bad ones), wrap each table in a view. At least that way, the view is the documentation of where the data is coming from.

Comment: We changed names because it's an old application that used some convention/names that aren't fit now, and we changed some structure so that it's quicker for the reporting application (less joins)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna throw this out there and say that I'd use Transaction Log shipping.  You can even set the secondary DBs to read-only.  There would be some setting up for full recovery mode and transaction log backups but that way you can just automatically restore the transaction logs to the secondary database and be hands-off with it and the secondary database would be as current as your last transaction log backup.

Depending on how current the data needs to be, if you only need it done daily you can set up something that will take your daily backups and then just restore them to the secondary.